# How to delete a cell in a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to let user delete a row in my app. But it is not working. I am new to app development so please help me.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    [self.userSelectedNamesAndMeaning removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
    [self.userSelectedNamesAndMeaning writeToFile:self.pathToPlist atomically:YES];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: is your method fired? Try: `NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);`

Comment: Did you get any error or exception?? Or try to debug this method and let me know whether this method called or not?

Comment: When you method doesn't get called make sure you've added `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: Yes, on right swipe I am seeing the delete action and on tap, it is calling this method.@user2509601

Comment: The problem seems to be with "indexPath" as it is not returning the key value. How to I know what is the key value of the row? @iProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to delete the Key value from the NSMutableDictionary and the solution is

```
   [self.userSelectedNamesAndMeaning removeObjectForKey:[self.allNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Where allNames is the NSArray storing all the names to paint the table.

Now the problem is with deleting the row from the UI and it is showing an exception error.

Comment: What is the exception? You could remove the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths call and just call [tableView reloadData]; after you have remove the item from your data structure. This will not be optimal if you have a large data set though. Posting the exception will help.

Comment: @Helium3 I tried that as well, and it is not reloading, if tap another tab and come back to this page, it is removing it. but [tableView ReloadData] is not reloading the tableView. Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Is the tableView created in a xib? You need to hook up the delegate and datasources to the view controller. You should add the UITableViewDelegate protocol to the .h file of the class owning the tableview.